# How to add user defined functions in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to solve a problem using Apache Storm. I have the following queries.

1. Is there any method to add user defined functions in Bolts other than the built in functions like `execute()`, `prepare()` etc? If possible, how to call such a function from `execute()`?
2. Also is it possible to add a 'recursive function' kind of logic in a Bolt?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can add any method to you bolt, and yes, it can also be recursive. I am not sure what you mean by "how to call such a function from `execute()` -- just call it from there -- it's a regular method:

```java
public class MyBolt extends IRichBolt {
    void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) { /* put your code here */ }
    void cleanup() { /* put your code here */ }
    void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) { /* put your code here */ }
    Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() { /* put your code here */ }

    void execute(Tuple input) {
        // just call the new methods
        int x = myFirstFunction();
        mySecondFunction(5);
    }

    // can also be public or protected etc (any return type or parameters are ok)
    private int myFirstFunction() {
        return 0;
    }
    // recursive
    private void mySecondFunction(int a) {
        while(--a > 0) {
            mySecondFunction(a);
        }
    }
}
```